Converting GUID to String (Finding convertion algorithm)
I have some GUIDs and their corresponding string values (an string which is including the values that made the GUID). Could you please help me to decrypt the GUID and find the decryption algorithm?
1) x=21911&y=13576&z=15&Key=M10 ==> GUID: 01222be88e737a1ec4c95eb10d7d4876
2) x=21912&y=13576&z=15&Key=M10 ==> GUID: 8cfdb1b6210d2809f6742ace77668355
3) x=336&y=215&z=9&Key=M10      ==> GUID: 0850c213e9bab24b7ebc7387d44a381e
4) x=22107&y=13838&z=15&Key=m10 ==> GUID: dcf4d5580cea3fc1b57e4625171602bd

Finding the algorithm to decrypt the GUID (GUID to String)
